# Spring MVC learning resources

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have a J2EE site which is running fine, main functionalities include display contents from MySQL, form validating, etc.

I want to pass this site to Spring MVC framework in one or two weeks, but I know nothing about Spring MVC. I decide to use Spring MVC + Maven.

I'm searching for good learning resources to let me do this. It should be easy to learn and project-based. I've read some of the guides from Spring website, it's good but too slow. I just want learn to build the same site with Spring and that's it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can find a lot of documentations, materials and examples by searching on Google and GitHub. You can also check http://spring.io, which contains excellent guides and examples.

Keep in mind Spring is a very large framework...you won't be able to learn everything about it by learning one or two tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

http://courses.caveofprogramming.com/ - you can try send an email and get the rest of his video tutorials. they are very good

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mH2jx2RCu7o&list=PLmcxdcWPhFqMq2BctGktOcIJKUw23wJeh

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/pdf/spring-framework-reference.pdf

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for paid resources then you should go with

1. [Spring & Hibernate for Beginners (includes Spring Boot)](https://www.udemy.com/course/spring-hibernate-tutorial/?ranMID=39197&ranEAID=CuIbQrBnhiw&ranSiteID=CuIbQrBnhiw-C0x_iK4gMprlsLVnt5.41A&LSNPUBID=CuIbQrBnhiw&utm_source=aff-campaign&utm_medium=udemyads) **5***
2. [Spring Boot Microservices with Spring Cloud Beginner to Guru](https://www.udemy.com/course/spring-boot-microservices-with-spring-cloud-beginner-to-guru/?ranMID=39197&ranEAID=JVFxdTr9V80&ranSiteID=JVFxdTr9V80-N4E_yrA_WY7B96WN0T.hXQ&LSNPUBID=JVFxdTr9V80&utm_source=aff-campaign&utm_medium=udemyads) **4***
3. [Learn Spring Boot - Rapid Spring Application Development](https://www.udemy.com/course/spring-boot-intro/?LSNPUBID=JVFxdTr9V80&ranEAID=JVFxdTr9V80&ranMID=39197&ranSiteID=JVFxdTr9V80-6VCuHVc_MdTYf7t2sjjyWQ&utm_medium=udemyads&utm_source=aff-campaign) **4***
4. [Learn Spring: The Certification Class](https://courses.baeldung.com/courses/ls-certification-class/lectures/29539284)

If you are looking for free resources then

1. https://www.youtube.com/c/JavaGuides **5***
2. https://www.youtube.com/c/LearnCodeWithDurgesh **4.5***
3. https://www.youtube.com/c/Telusko **4***

*Tip: The best way to learn Spring Boot if you have prior exposure to Java and Spring Framework is to build a simple application.*